# Sphere collision test reacts too quickly

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm writing a game for Android using Java and OpenGL. I can render everything perfectly to screen, but when I try to check whether two objects collide or not, my algorithm detects a collision before it occurs on the screen.

Here's how I test for collision:

```
for(int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++) {
    float enemyRadius = enemies.elementAt(i).worldSpaceBoundingSphereRadius();
    float[] enemyPosition = enemies.elementAt(i).getWorldSpaceCoordinates();

    for(int j=0; j<qubieBullets.size(); j++) {
        float bulletRadius = bullets.elementAt(j).worldSpaceBoundingSphereRadius();
        float[] bulletPosition = bullets.elementAt(j).getWorldSpaceCoordinates();

        float[] distanceVector = Vector3f.subtract(enemyPosition, bulletPosition);
        float distance = Vector3f.length(distanceVector);

        if(distance < (enemyRadius + bulletRadius)) {
            enemies.remove(i);
            qubieBullets.remove(j);

            i--;
            j--;

            // Reset enemy position
        }
    }
}
```

When the enemy cube (represented by a sphere for collision detection) closes in on the player, the player shoots a bullet (also a cube represented by a sphere) toward the enemy. My expectations are that the enemy gets reset when the bullet hits him on screen, but it happens way earlier than that.

The methods for calculation world space position and radius:

```
public float[] getWorldSpaceCoordinates() {

    float[] modelSpaceCenter = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    float[] worldSpaceCenter = new float[4];
    Matrix.multiplyMV(worldSpaceCenter, 0, getModelMatrix(), 0, modelSpaceCenter, 0);
    return new float[] {worldSpaceCenter[0]/worldSpaceCenter[3], worldSpaceCenter[1]/worldSpaceCenter[3], worldSpaceCenter[2]/worldSpaceCenter[3]};
}

public float worldSpaceBoundingSphereRadius() {
    float[] arbitraryVertex = new float[] {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    float[] worldSpaceVector = new float[4];
    Matrix.multiplyMV(worldSpaceVector, 0, getModelMatrix(), 0, arbitraryVertex, 0);
    float[] xyz = new float[] {worldSpaceVector[0]/worldSpaceVector[3], worldSpaceVector[1]/worldSpaceVector[3], worldSpaceVector[2]/worldSpaceVector[3]};
    return Vector3f.length(xyz);
}
```

Is it my code or math that's wrong? I can't think of anything more to try, and would be helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: If you're using cubes, (unless `getModelMatrix()` is transforming it beyond rotation) you can simplify your radius calculation to `rad = sqrt( 3 * (x/2) * (x/2) )` where `x` is the length of one cube edge.  Also, I'm assuming the early collisions you're noticing are VERY early because when using spheres to detect cube collisions, that's gonna happen anyway.

Comment: When do you do this collision checking? If you do it before rendering, it might seem like it's early because the actual collision is never rendered.

Comment: What does "way earlier" mean?

Comment: The collision detection is performed right after the cubes has been updated (scaled, translated and rotated) and drawn (using the model matrix retrieved by getModelMatrix()). Collision is detected pretty much instantly when the screen is pressed. As early as seen in this picture: http://i.imgur.com/QVWYJva.png

Answer (score 0):

Your `worldSpaceBoundingSphereRadius()` is most likely the culprit.  `arbitraryVertex` is a Vector of (1,1,1) so your math will only work if the cube model has edges of length `2 * sqrt(1/3)`.  What you want to do is find the exact length of your cube's model's edge, use the formula from my comment (`rad = sqrt( 3 * (x/2) * (x/2) )`) and use that radius for your `arbitraryVertex` (`rad,rad,rad,1`).

Also, your dividing the results of your multiplication by the homogenous coordinate (`worldSpaceVector[0]/worldSpaceVector[3]`).  With a proper rotation, translation, or scale, the homogenous coordinate should always be exactly `1` (if it started as one).  If it isn't, you might have a projection matrix in there or something else that isn't a basic transformation.

EDIT:

Since you're using `worldSpaceBoundingSphereRadius()` to get only the radius, you want only the scaling component of `getModelMatrix()`.  If that returns scaling *and* translation, this translation will apply to your radius and make it much larger than it actually is.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't make any difference. The arbitraryVertex (1,1,1) is the vector from the centre of the cube to one of the corners (the cube is 2x2x2 units, centered on 0). Correct me if I'm wrong, but this ought to be the radius vector in model space?

Comment: Also, I did not know that scaling, translating and rotating doesn't affect the homogeneous coordinate. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @SvenG If it's a 2x2x2 cube centered around 0, its bounding sphere radius is sqrt(3) or ~1.73205.

Comment: @SvenG Of course considering that mistake, if that was the bug you'd be having the opposite problem (collisions detected too late).  Is `getModelMatrix()` doing anything beyond simple transforms?

Comment: I think my problem might be that I'm trying to transform the radius into world space, since I thought the length would vary from model space. If I simply return `sqrt(3) * mScalingFactor`, works. Why do I not have to recalculate the length

Comment: The getModelMatrix() simply returns the stored model matrix, which also is used to render. It does not do anything but basic transformations.

Comment: @SvenG Ah!  It makes sense now.  I added some stuff to my answer under *EDIT*.